# C++ How to create an 2d array, pass it to another function, and print it

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, printf

How can I create an 2d array in one function and then pass it to some other function which prints it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Answer (score -2):

Because it took me ages to find this I'm just gonna put this here. My goal was to create a 2d array, pass it to some function (in this case a 'printer') and then let that function print the 2d array for me because I didn't want to repeat it and/or write it every sexing time to know what the 2d array looked like.

```
void pre(int *grid, int x, int y) {
    const int base = 8;
    for (int y = 0; y < base; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < base; x++) {
            printf("%d ", *(grid+x*base+y));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const int base = 8;
    int cursor = 0;
    int grid[base][base];
    for (int y = 0; y < base; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < base; x++) {
            grid[x][y] = x;
        }
    }
    pre((int*)grid, base, base);
}
```

PS1: Source: [YouTube video by CppNuts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEKmS221MtM&t=4m57s)

PS2: I sincerely hope someone is helped with this, not a weird attempt for upvotes.